# xUnit integration tests in .NET Core gives error "An item with the same key has already been added"

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit

I am using xUnit to perform integration tests in a .NET Core application. I am following the integration tests section of [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing). It introduced me to a TestFixture which hosts the project in an in-memory server. The Startup code initializes an in-memory database with two records in an Assets table.. The tests are shown below.

The problem I have is that when I run these tests, they fail with the error: An item with the same key has already been added

I assume it's because the Startup is trying to add the same two records in the database for every test. If I run the tests a second time, they pass. When I run them a third time they fail, and alternate like this. When I put a breakpoint in the Starup code that initalizes the database, it looks like there are two threads trying to execute the breakpoint line because when I press F10 to go to the next line, the execution stays on the same line. How can I confirm that this is the problem? If it really is THAT!

```
public class AssetControllerTests : IClassFixture<TestFixture<ManagementSystemCore.Startup>>
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public AssetControllerTests(TestFixture<ManagementSystemCore.Startup> fixture)
    {
        _client = fixture.Client;
    }

    private List<Asset> GetTestAssets()
    {
        return Startup.GetTestAssets();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Assets_ReturnsAViewResult_WithListOfAssets()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockRepo = new Mock<IAssetRepository>();
        mockRepo.Setup(repo => repo.ListAsync()).Returns(Task.FromResult(GetTestAssets()));

        try
        {
            var controller = new AssetController(mockRepo.Object);
            // Act
            var result = await controller.Assets();

            // Assert
            var viewResult = Assert.IsType<ViewResult>(result);
            var model = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IEnumerable<AssetViewModel>>(viewResult.ViewData.Model);
            Assert.Equal(2, model.Count());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var msg = e.Message;
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Details_ReturnsViewResult_WithOneAsset()
    {
        // Arrange - get an asset known to exist
        var testAssets = Startup.GetTestAssets();
        var id = testAssets.Select(a => a.Id).First();

        // Act
        var response = await _client.GetAsync("/asset/details/" + id);

        // Assert
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Assert.True(responseString.Contains(testAssets.Select(a => a.SerialNumber).First()));
        Assert.True(responseString.Contains(testAssets.Select(a => a.PartNumber).First()));
    }        

    [Fact]
    public async Task PostAsync_ReturnsBadRequest_GivenNullModel()
    {
        // Arrange & Act
        var mockRepo = new Mock<IAssetRepository>();
        var controller = new AssetController(mockRepo.Object);
        controller.ModelState.AddModelError("error", "some error");

        // Act
        var result = await controller.PostAsync(null);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsType<BadRequestObjectResult>(result);
    }
}
```

Here is the Startup code:

```
    public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase());

        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddScoped<ITodoRepository, TodoRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IAssetRepository, AssetRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IValuesRepository, ValuesRepository>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            var repository = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IAssetRepository>();

            InitializeDatabaseAsync(repository).Wait();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Asset}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }

    // Load the database with sample assets
    public async Task InitializeDatabaseAsync(IAssetRepository repo)
    {
        var assetList = await repo.ListAsync();
        if (!assetList.Any())
        {
            foreach (var asset in GetTestAssets())
            {
                await repo.AddAsync(asset);
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<Asset> GetTestAssets()
    {
        return new List<Asset>()
        {
            new Asset("5eb6eb60-72d7-4f51-b209-22a4d97604bd", "SN1234", "PN1234"),
            new Asset("4dc5fd59-98d7-3g34-c310-47g5e84987cg", "SN5678", "PN5678")
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet?

Comment: @Groppe What I learned is that DbContext is not thread-safe. And that I was writing a web application where each request creates a new instance of the DbContext. In xUnit, multiple integration test classes create multiple instances of Startup on different threads. Each thread created the same data, so the error occurred because the threads were each inserting the same data. I believe what I did as a temporary solution was to make the DbContext a singleton so that the same instance was used on subsequent web requests. When I did that it worked, but not sure if it is the best solution.